# Trouble interpreting java stack trace

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a stack trace that I need some help interpreting:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 36 >= 36
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.getNode(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:976)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.getPreferredHeight(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:274)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.updateCachedPreferredSize(BasicTreeUI.java:1823)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTreeUI.java:1924)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTreeUI.java:1912)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1642)
    at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:769)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1420)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1409)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1506)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1479)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:698)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:695)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1679)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

None of the files or functions in the stack are for my program, so it must, by my reckoning, be 100% internal to swing.  That's not to say it's not probably my program at fault though.

I can pretty much get the gist of what the JVM is doing at the time - it looks like it is repainting one of my JTree components which is in a scroll pane (I have a few, so I have no clue which it might be).

My best guess as to what might cause this error is that the content of the tree (and hence the number of nodes in it) changes at some point during the repainting, so the vector that stores the child nodes changes in size whilst it's being worked through to get the component sizes.

Is that sounding plausible?

If that is the case, how can I get round it?  I guess I'd want to block the repainting while any updating is going on, or conversely block the updating while any repainting is going on?

Comment: Just a quick note to say that I think your hypothesis does sound plausible. Afraid can't offer anything by way to canonical solutions.

Comment: It might take a while, but you should step through with debugger and find out exactly where it was failing. Then take action based on that info

Comment: @redFIVE I'd love to, but unfortunately this is a report from a customer :(

Comment: @Majenko, ugh, that sucks man. Do you have the same source code as them, are you able to reproduce?

Comment: The program is mine, but the error doesn't seem to occur for me (yet). I have another thought: the trees get updated from multiple different sources, It may be possible that there is a collision between two threads both updating it at once?

Comment: I find the `Exception` message hilarious. Can't help but +1 for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way Swing "blocks repainting while updating is going on" is to limit any changes to the UI to the event dispatch thread; if you don't know (or the program author doesn't/didn't know) what that is, it's some indication to being part of the problem.

The error message (about which I find nothing amusing, incidentally) is saying that there is a vector (the generic collections had not come along when Swing was written) with 36 elements in it, at indices 0-35; the code attempted to access index 36 of this vector, and hence the exception.

I would look for portions of the UI that are changing under whatever conditions this happens -- is it a data change, window resize, what?  The fact that the vector has 36 elements should give you some clues -- do you have a place with that many buttons of whatever type, or whatever?  I suppose it could also be a window with 36 components; does the UI have a place where a component disappears from a window?

In the same area, I'd look for some code that calls something like paint or repaint that is outside of the event dispatch thread -- all such code must be done in that thread.  Look at SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait() for a way to do this without a lot of futzing with existing code, if it needs this.

Comment: I am assuming (guessing) that it is one of my trees.  They can very easily have 36+ elements in them.  I don't do any paint or repaint calls at all, but I do have some nodeStructureChanged() calls.  There's lots of node adding / removing happening from multiple threads, including Timer threads, threads spawned from the EDT, and other places.

Comment: OMG! I just had it happen for me! That's a help at least, I can now replicate it.  It's a "random" thing that happens when it feels like it (program sat there with no user interaction).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think you have pointed me in the right direction. I have wrapped my Timer event in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() and I think it has cured the problem.  I guess the Timer's EDT isn't the same as Swing's EDT...!

Comment: Actually, it has just moved the problem elsewhere. I have more data now though as the trace it gives is more useful. It's being fired as a result of a javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel.nodeStructureChanged() call now.

Comment: However, now I have the invokeLater I don't seem to need the nodeStructureChanged call.

Comment: Glad to have been of help.  In case you haven't already run across it yet, another tool to debug this sort of thing is SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(), which tells you if the thread running the call is the (UI) event dispatch thread.  Good luck.

Comment: That's a useful one - I'll remember that.  Maybe add it into my crash reports, actually...